# Perform arithmetic in select statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Let's suppose I have balance 2000, and want to select balance as

```
balance=balance-Cr+Dr
```

So my balance column will give values as below.

```
balance        DR            Cr
40000          0             60000  
100000         60000         0
0              0             100000
```

How is this possible in SQL query?

Please check similar question like me
[enter link description here](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Adding-some-Values-to-Running-Total-in-Crystal-Report-8-5-AJ4UCPcxC4.html)

Comment: It looks like your missing information or some output: I can't reconcile "balance = 2000" with the values in the table given. At all. RonK's answer may do what you want though

Comment: You could use computed column - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx if you want to be able to select this from many places witout doing the calculation each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a recursive CTE that calculates the balance using the balance from the previous row. You need something that defines the order of the rows. I use the ID column in the sample table.

```
-- Test table
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  DR int,
  Cr int
)

-- Sample data
insert into @T (DR, Cr)
select 0,     60000  union all
select 60000, 0      union all
select 0,     100000

-- In value
declare @StartBalance int
set @StartBalance = 100000

-- Recursive cte calculating balance as a running sum
;with cte as
(
  select 
    T.ID,
    @StartBalance - T.Cr + T.DR as Balance,
    T.DR, 
    T.Cr
  from @T as T
  where T.ID = 1
  union all
  select 
    T.ID,
    C.Balance - T.Cr + T.DR as Balance,
    T.DR, 
    T.Cr
  from cte as C
    inner join @T as T
      on C.ID+1 = T.ID  
)
select Balance, DR, Cr
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
Balance     DR          Cr
----------- ----------- -----------
40000       0           60000
100000      60000       0
0           0           100000
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT (T.BALANCE-T.CR+T.DR) as "Balance", T.DR, T.CR
FROM <table-name> T
```

Comment: I want balance from previous select result.See the result of 2nd row of my table balance of previous row is 40000 and cr and db of this row is(0,60000) so this row balance be balnace of previous row+ dr-cr(from current row ) that is 100000

Comment: Then how does the balance go from 100000 in the second row to 0 in the third row with a dr/cr of (60000,0)? Shouldn't the third row then be (40000,x,y)?

Comment: @Zain - so my answer is not what you are looking for. Please add more information into the question - it is not clear at all what your initial data is and what you want to retrieve. 
Also, looks like your record structure could use some refactoring - I'm not sure you are holding the data in the correct structure.
Example: A balance is the sum of all credits and debits - so a table with 3 columns (ID, TYPE, VALUE) where ID is the account identifier, Type is either Credit/Debit and value is the amount to credit/debit will probably be better

Comment: Cr of 3rd row is 100000 and Dr is 0,Balance from previous row is 100000.So balance of current row will be 100000(2nd row balnace)-100000(3rd row cr)+0(3rd row db) that is 0;

Comment: @Zain - your data structure is not clear - what business entity does each record represent? What does the table maintain?

Comment: @Zain - Your input does not make arithmetic sense, please add more details in the question (not as a comment here) and explain the scenario - do you need to run a single query on the last record? Do you need to perform the balance calculation while inserting a new credit/debit record? Do you need something that will take a table with 0 balance in all rows and calculate the balance correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle, there is a function called `LAG` to reach the previous row data: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/lag.html

If you read this link I think you will see that this is exactly what you need. But only if you use Oracle..